Registros unicos
estoy intentando sacar una lista de registros unicos de un excel, he visto un archivo en el cual usaban un csv, pero yo quiero utilizar un archivo excel.
Utilizo este codigo:
 with warnings.catch_warnings():
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)
df = pd.read_excel(file_path,[1])

Esto es lo que muestra la variable df
 {1:         COD         DESTINO MUNICIPIO     CP PROVINCIA   CAE COD_TIPO  \
0    xxxxxx     fsdgfdsgdsg   ggfdgfd    123    gfdhfd  1111       ES   
  1  erqewrew         gfsgfds       gfg  12343  hgfdhgfd  1111       ES   
   2    ewqrew  gfsdgfdsgfhdsf   fggdsgf  4t545   hgfdhfd  1111       ES   
 3     reqwr       gfdsgfdsg  gfdsgfdg  43543  hgfdhfdg   111       ES   
 4     erqwr         gfdsgds   gffdsgf  54654   hgfhfdh  1111       GC   

   COD_DEST       TITULAR        NIF  
 0       123  dgfssfdgfsdg      gfdsg  
 1        12      gfdgdhsh      gfdsg  
 2        43       gsdgfds  gfdsgdgds  
    3     43242  gfdsgdsgsdfg   gfdgfdsg  
 4      4324       gsdgdsg  gfdsgdsgd  }

 # Obtenemos los codigos únicos
  codigo = df["COD"].unique()

Cuando vuelco los datos en la variable para ver los unicos me sale este error
"name": "KeyError",
"message": "'COD'",
"stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[115], line 2
      1 # Obtenemos los codigos únicos
----> 2 codigo = df["COD"].unique()

KeyError: 'COD'"

que es lo que puede ocurrir??
Esto es lo que devuelve cuando hago print(type(df)) y print(dir("COD"))
<class 'dict'> 
['add', 'class', 'contains', 'delattr', 'dir', 'doc', 'eq', 'format', 'ge', 'getattribute', 'getitem', 'getnewargs', 'getstate', 'gt', 'hash', 'init', 'init_subclass', 'iter', 'le', 'len', 'lt', 'mod', 'mul', 'ne', 'new', 'reduce', 'reduce_ex', 'repr', 'rmod', 'rmul', 'setattr', 'sizeof', 'str', 'subclasshook', 'capitalize', 'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'format_map', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isascii', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'removeprefix', 'removesuffix', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']

Muchas gracias
print(dir(def))
['class', 'class_getitem', 'contains', 'delattr', 'delitem', 'dir', 'doc', 'eq', 'format', 'ge', 'getattribute', 'getitem', 'getstate', 'gt', 'hash', 'init', 'init_subclass', 'ior', 'iter', 'le', 'len', 'lt', 'ne', 'new', 'or', 'reduce', 'reduce_ex', 'repr', 'reversed', 'ror', 'setattr', 'setitem', 'sizeof', 'str', 'subclasshook', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']

Hay un key error en cod... estás seguro que entras de ese modo a la variable ? df["COD"].unique() ??? Prueba a mostrar df y ver que contiene, luego de que lo cargas.

No me muestra nada después de cargar los datos únicos, ya que es donde me da el error. Indico lo que me muestra la variable df antes de hacer los registros únicos. Entiendo que no me reconoce la primera fila como cabecera de los registros, pero no se cómo solucionarlo

Ok, entonces he de suponer que df es una cadena string larga? Por favor haz un print(type(df)) y print(dir(mi_variable))

No, df sería df = pd.read_excel(file_path,[1]). Una variable que carga el contenido de una hoja de Excel. Y de en la otra variable código quiero guardar los registros únicos de la columna "Cod". No sé si me estoy explicando correctamente.

Si, esa es la asignación, pero haz un print de esa variable con lo que te pase.

Mi objetivo sería. Leer una hoja Excel, obtener los registros únicos de una columna, después hacer un filtro de cada registro único y después guardar dicho resultado en otro libro de Excel por cada registro único

Puedes hacer un print(dir(df)) igual ?? que recien noto que quedó "mi_variable" en vez de haberla cambiado a df como debería ser.

Ya estaria en el enunciado lo que muestra print(dir(df)). Gracias

De todos modos, ahora no veo que df contenga algún cod, si veo doc

Solucionado: he estado probando y parece que el error estaba en la lectura de la hoja
df = pd.read_excel(file_path,[1]) estaba mal
df = pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name='DESTINOS') manera correcta

Fue lo primero que dije que estaba mal y que verificaras jsjsjsjs

@Principiante Por favor elabora uan respuesta con el código actualizado y la solución encontrada. Trata de explicar como era el error y que cambia en la solución. Luego mas tarde, te podes aceptar la respuesta solito xD
